# Angular2 in Java Spring project

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, angular

I want to build a project which has Java Spring as the backend and ng2 as the frontend. After building the project I want to have a `war` file to deploy. I placed `"angular-quickstart"` into `webapp/resource` and then installed `package.json` by `npm`. Eclispe always leaks memory because of too many files.

Can you show me how to get over it? Do I need config something, or is it OK with this folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

As @tan9 suggests, Develop front-end and back-end **separately**. For back-end you can have eclipse, tomcat, Spring rest. For front-end, create new project using `angular-cli` (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), in folder **OUTSIDE** eclipse workspace.

After development use `ng build --prod` to create an optimized set of html-js files in `dist` directory in angular project.

Depends on your requirement you can copy all these to your eclipse `Project/WebContent` folder; if this is the case, use `<base href=".">` in index.html.

Answer (score 0):

You should only packaged the compiled resources into your WAR archive.
Try https://github.com/angular/angular-cli , and only package the `dist` folder created by running `ng build`.

Or you should try to separate `frontend` and `backend` into two Maven modules, package `frontend` as a jar, and place all built resources into `jar/META-INF/resources`. And the set the `frontend` jar module as a dependency of the `backend` war module.